# setting the website body min-width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a responsive website which need to set for a minimum width. now the problem is that when the browser is being resized the width changes and after 768px all the elements breaks. I've tried setting the body for 769px but most elements still breaks. how can I set the body (the whole website size) size to minimum 769px, with css or javascript.

note: I don't think I can change all the elements to a min-width now, because there's too many things to change.

Comment: Can you wrap the entire contents of the body in another element? You could then set the min-width on that.

Comment: I think more information is needed to answer this question. What do you mean by "all the elements breaks"? Are they positioned incorrectly? Is their content overlapping? How are you positioning these elements?

Comment: You should use more semantic markup in your HTML, then it should be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a wrapper div as first child of the body and give it min-width all the other elements will be child of wrapper div.

Comment: I did this but still the child elements inside this div is changing size, as I resize browser smaller than the limit I've set this main wrapper

Comment: If you post the code, it will be easy to identify. If you are using media queries then you should use percentages to your site elements. As media queries will consider the browser width regardless of the container min width.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using responsive units that size with the page like rem and em units, rather than pixels. Your page should adjust accordingly if you are using responsive units. Wrap your sections in [flex containers](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) and adjust accordingly.